# Docker-compose runs into an error due to Socket Address

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

When trying to build and run my docker project using docker-compose up, it returns me this error output:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/eA3NHfZ]

I have deleted all old containers, I'm not in swarm mode, and I have no more dockers images or containers running so ... I don't know why there is a problem about sockets in 5000 port.

Thanks buddies.

EDIT: It doesn't matter if I change the port on the docker-compose.yml, console will throw me the same issue.

EDIT 2: After changing the port to 9000:9000 in docker-compose.yml:

[image: click here to see the screenshot]

Comment: Please, update the question with the error text as external links can become inactive over time.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates the port 5000 is already in use. Please change up the port mapping to bind to some other port.

Comment: I have changed it like 3 times and still getting the same problem.